# Removing all but one of a certain character in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue where I'm trying to remove all of the `'.'` from the string/filename below in SSMS apart from the last one which dictates file type.

```
EPC 14.10.14.pdf
```

Ideally I would like this string to appear as below:

```
EPC 141014.pdf
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `replace,substring` and `len` function

```
select replace(substring(@x,0,len(@x) - 3),'.','') + substring(@x,len(@x) - 3,len(@x))
```

**EDIT:**
If the name extension has a variable length, you can use the following query

```
select 
   CONCAT(
     replace(substring(@x,0,len(@x) - CHARINDEX('.',TRIM(REVERSE(@x)))),'.','')
   , 
     substring(@x,len(@x) - CHARINDEX('.',TRIM(REVERSE(@x))),len(@x))
   )
```

***[Result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7926284c7eaed5ab0886e371a4763b1c)***

Comment: As @Zhorov already pointed out,  extensions could have a different length (e.g. docx, xls, cs)

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I also added a name query with a variable length extension.

Answer (score 1):

**As a variable :**

> ```
> declare @doc varchar(30) = 'EPC 14.10.14.pdf'
>
> declare @ext varchar(8) = right(@doc, charindex('.', reverse(@doc)));
> set @doc = concat(replace(left(@doc,len(@doc)-len(@ext)),'.',''), @ext);
>
> select @doc as doc;
> ```

| doc |
| --- |
| EPC 141014.pdf |

**As a table column :**

> ```
> create table test (
>  doc varchar(30) not null
> );
>
> insert into test (doc) values
> ('EPC 14.10.14.pdf'), 
> ('FQD 15.11.15.jpeg');
>
> select doc
> , undotted_doc = concat(replace(left(doc, len(doc)-charindex('.', reverse(doc))),'.',''), right(doc, charindex('.', reverse(doc))))
> from test;
> ```

| doc | undotted_doc |
| --- | --- |
| EPC 14.10.14.pdf | EPC 141014.pdf |
| FQD 15.11.15.jpeg | FQD 151115.jpeg |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=dace7919bd905041e72625fb8b31be63)*

Answer (score 0):

If you have extensions with different length (e.g. `docx`, `xls`), you need to find the index of the last occurrence of the `.` character using `REVERSE()` and `CHARINDEX()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT( 
   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SomeText, 1, LEN(SomeText) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(SomeText))), '.', ''),
   STUFF(SomeText, 1, LEN(SomeText) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(SomeText)), '')
) AS FileName
FROM (VALUES
   ('EPC 14.10.14.pdf'),
   ('EPC 14.10.14.docx'),
   ('14.10.14.xlsx')
) t (SomeText)
```

Result:

```
FileName
----------------
EPC 141014.pdf
EPC 141014.docx
141014.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way.

**SQL**

```
SELECT fileName AS [Before]
    , CONCAT(CONCAT(PARSENAME(fileName,4), PARSENAME(fileName,3), PARSENAME(fileName,2))
    , '.', PARSENAME(fileName,1)) AS [After]
FROM (VALUES
   ('EPC 14.10.14.pdf'),
   ('EPC 14.10.14.docx'),
   ('14.10.14.xlsx'),
   ('csharp.10.14.cs')
) AS t(fileName);
```

**Output**

```
+-------------------+-----------------+
|      Before       |      After      |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| EPC 14.10.14.pdf  | EPC 141014.pdf  |
| EPC 14.10.14.docx | EPC 141014.docx |
| 14.10.14.xlsx     | 141014.xlsx     |
| csharp.10.14.cs   | csharp1014.cs   |
+-------------------+-----------------+
```